# Как сделать подсветку поля, картинки и т.д.также как и в валидации Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать подсветку полей в Bootstrap как на скриншоте, просто валидация мне не нужна, интересует подсветка картинки, поля, добавление галочки. На примере:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 selectContainer">
            <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
            <input type="text" name="User" id="User" class="form-control">
            </div>
            </div>
```

Спасибо за ответы, не будьте строги к начинающим.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что в данном контексте считается подсветкой? в бутстрепе, по сути, меняется цвет текста, цвет фона и добавляется символ (напр., галочка), вот и вся стилизация. чтобы это сделать, надо создать класс с этой стилизацией и добавлять его нужным полям.

Comment: Спасибо, за идею, попробую сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation
посмотрите тут, вроде бы ваш случай?
там чуть-чуть ниже будут и с картинкой перед инпутом и с галочкой

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, читать мануал нужно подробнее ))